# Ios image notification from firebase web api using php

Tags: php, ios, firebase

I am working on sending notification to ios. Notification without image is working perfectly but not with image. When i search the solution, they all say like set 'mutable-content' => true. yeah, but how? I may be so dumb enough not to understand what that actually means. the params I sent is this ..

```
$arr = ['type' => 'msg', 'data' => '', 'text' => 'Hello', 'image_url' => ''];
$fields = array(
           'to' => '/topics/iostest',
           'notification' => $arr,
           'mutable-content'=> 1,
           'priority' => 'high'
          );
```

Ios only read the 'notification' and receive like ..

```
'aps': {
   alert : 'Hello'
}
```

not receiving 'mutable-content' ... 
the people who work on both ios and php can solve this, i hope. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the word *mutable-content* in your JSON. Please set *mutable_content* instead of *mutable-content*. APNS automatically convert it.

Use below JSON format for rich push notification 
NB: *content_available* field in JSON is optional and *mutable_content* is required.

```
{
   "to": "dWB537Nz1GA:APA91bHIjJ5....",
   "content_available": true,
   "mutable_content": true,
   "data":
   {
      "message": "Offer!",
      "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
   },
   "notification":
   {
      "body": "Enter your message",
      "sound": "default"
   }
}
```

***And you should get a payload like this***

{

```
aps =     {

    alert = "Enter your message";

    "content-available" = 1;

    "mutable-content" = 1;

    sound = default;

};

"gcm.message_id" = "0:1498075182894674%4e5015e84e5015e8";

mediaUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG";

message = "Offer!";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this json format for push notification from firebase your json fromat should be

```
{ "registration_ids" : [Send Array of Device Token], "data" : {
"image_url" : "send your image here"
  "message" : "Send your message here" },"notification" : {
"title" : "APP Name",
"sound" : "default",
"priority" : "high" }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my code is also working perfectly for sending push notification without image. my problem is that I can't send notification with image.

Comment: Have you try above format for send push with image ?
In push notification have limit you can send large data so